# javascript fs seach files for strings in array. Avoid bad performance

Tags: javascript, node.js, big-o, fs, ramda.js

I'm building a tool that will clean up a JSON file containing localization strings if they are no longer in use in the source code.

First, I parse the localization file into an array with all the id's that are (or no longer are) used in the source code to get the string value in the right language.

so I have an array looking something like this:

```
const ids = ['home.title', 'home.description', 'menu.contact', 'menu.social'];
```

etc. you get the point.

I'm using node.js fs promisified readFile and glob to search .js source code files like this:

```
const jsFiles = await globbing('./**/*.js', {cwd: directory, ignore: './**/*test.js'});
const results = jsFiles.map(async file => {
  const filePath = path.join(directory, file);
  return readFile(filePath, 'utf8').then((data) => {
      // handle match here
  }).catch(console.log);
});
```

I also have Ramda available for fancy list/collection functions, but no other libraries.

So, I will be able to loop through the ids array and for each item scan the entire source code for a match with the function from above. But that seems a bit overkill to scan the entire source code times ids.length. The ids array is on around 400 ids' and the source code is hundreds of large files.

To avoid O(M*N), is there a way to match the entire array with the entire source code, and discard the not matched array items? Or what would be the best practice here?

current solution:

```
const cleanLocal = async () => {
  const localIdList = Object.keys(await getLocalMap());
  const matches = [];
  localIdList.map(async id => {
    const directory = path.join(__dirname, '..');
    const jsFiles = await globbing('./**/*.js', {cwd: directory, ignore: './**/*test.js'});
    jsFiles.map(async file => {
      const filePath = path.join(directory, file);
      return readFile(filePath, 'utf8').then((data) => {
        if (data.indexOf(id) >= 0) {
          console.log(id);
          matches.push(id);
        }
      }).catch(console.log);
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: I'm not sure but I think that question about best practices, are not good for StackOverflow there is even close reason (Primary Opinion Based).

Comment: what do you want to do with the matched value? because the method change accordingly

Comment: I would want to end up with two arrays, one with matched ids and one with not matched ids.

Comment: How are you parsing the files to match translation keys? Are you just doing a straight search? Because that might yield a false positive like `home = {}; home.title = "blah"` as in, it's *not* a key but it matches one. This is valid and you can try to refine the matches manually. Or are you actually only finding real usages of translation keys? In that case, you may just try extracting all keys from all files and do an intersection with the keys from the translation file.

Comment: On a separate note, this seems like a tool you won't be using all the time. It's either a one-off or maybe doing a periodic sweep. If I'm correct in this, I think it's fine to have bad performance - optimising one-off tasks isn't really worth it.

Comment: can you post how do you plan to do it normally (how you plan to scan the file and compare it with the first value no need for the others)

Comment: Good idea. coming up. And true, the tool is supposed to be used once a month or so. performance wise it is not an big issue in that context, but I would like to understand how to avoid (if possible) to scan ids.length * source code files

Comment: `I would like to understand how to avoid (if possible) to scan ids.length * source code files` that's fair enough, I believe. While I think it's not needed to optimise this, I also think it can be a valuable learning opportunity.

Comment: I have added the proposed solution, that scans the source code multiple times. (not optimised) the array/collection 'const matches = [];' is the result after execution.

Answer (score 2):

You can't avoid the `O(M*N)` complexity in this case.

However, to improve performance you can switch the order of your operations: first loop over the files and then loop over the array. This is because looping over the files is a costly IO operation, while looping over the array is a fast memory operation.

In your code, you have `M` memory operations and `M*N` IO (filesystem) operations.

If you first loop over the files, you would have `N` IO operations and `M*N` memory operations.

Comment: Ok, that seems logical. But, (please correct me if this is insane) what if I scan then source code just once, and store the entire source code in a string. Then the IO operations would be down to one, but the memory operations would be more heavy since the match would take in a very large string, maybe even too large for the memory? Would this be beneficial, and even possible ?

Comment: @RasmusPuls well, you'd be loading each file from the disk in any case. You may as well load one -> process -> load another -> process etc., so you don't gobble up a large chunk of memory in one go.

Comment: it's not different if you scan the entire source code: you still have to go through all the files once and then perform M*N memory operations

Comment: Alright thanks for sharing your knowledge. I have posted a proposed answer, do you agree with my code in the context of what you write in your answer?

Answer (score 1):

As it is not possible to avoid O(M*N) in this case I have only been able to optimize this search function by looping through the source files once and then over the ids' for each file as proposed by @mihai as an optimization opportunity.

The end result looks like this:

```
const cleanLocal = async () => {
  const localIdList = Object.keys(await getLocalMap()); // ids' array
  const matches = [];
  const directory = path.join(__dirname, '..');
  const jsFiles = await globbing('./**/*.js', {cwd: directory, ignore: './**/*test.js'}); // list of files to scan
  const results = jsFiles.map(async file => {
    const filePath = path.join(directory, file);
    return readFile(filePath, 'utf8').then((data) => {
      localIdList.map(id => {
        if (R.contains(id, data)) { // R = ramda.js
          matches.push(id);
        }
      });
    }).catch(console.log);
  });
  await Promise.all(results);
  console.log('matches: ' + R.uniq(matches).length);
  console.log('in local.json: ' + localIdList.length);
};
```

Please let me know if there are any other way to optimize this.

Comment: There might be some reasonable clean-up, making the outer `map` a `reduce` and the inner one a `filter`.  That outer loop could simply concatenate the matches.  These likely wouldn't significantly change performance, but they could make the code easier to read.